# supressing a line if a subreport is empty in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report made on crystal reports that one of its fields is a subreport. I have a line object drew below this subreport for division purposes.

Something like this:

```
| SUBREPORT |
------------- (line object)
```

Is there a way to supress this line if my subreport is empty? I've tried to use a bottom border on the subreport, but it won't align with the rest of the report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a section below the sub report and add line in that section. Now write your supress condition for that section so that line gets supressed

Answer (score 1):

Line's don't have a conditional-suppression property.  You will need to place the line in its own section, then suppress the section when desired.

Comment: I didn't know that until further search. Crystal is cool and all, but sometimes it troubles you more than helps.